# "view my site" not showing in outlook?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

We have a Sharepoint 2007 deployment, Office Communicator, and Outlook 2007.
Inside my Outlook 2007 client, I can see a "View my site" option when clicking the prescence icon beside a user's name or meeting room when adding them as a recipient to a meeting request or email.
Our secretary doesn't have this option.

Is there anything I can look at as to why she doesn't have this option?  She has all the other options, but it seems to me her outlook/sharepoint integration isn't complete.  What can be done to fix this/look into the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured this out.
It seems our secretary recently got married, and although her Active Directory information was changed, and as a result, her my site on sharepoint was changed as well (//server/mysite/newname), it seems Office Communicator still was pointing to her old my site (//server/mysite/oldname).  This confused the OCS link icon in Outlook, causing it not to appear.
Changing her name in OCS allowed her access to "view my sites" link in Outlook (and everywhere else).